# Vertically centering an image within a fixed sized element: offset on the top

Tags: css

I want to display thumbnail images within fixed sized square containers, centering the thumbnails horizontally and vertically.

Using the `height`, `line-height` and `vertical-align` CSS properties, I can almost achieve it, but there's a small offset on the top (`2px` in my example) and **I'd like to understand why**.

As a workaround, I can set a negative top margin to the image, but I'd like to avoid it if possible (more prone to breaking across browsers?). I'm also surprised that I need a `-4px` top margin to counteract the `2px` offset.

Any hint?

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/N6Rme/

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you want to this

remove `margin -minus` and add **border** in **ul** and **li** as like this

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/N6Rme/5/

Answer (score 0):

I not found any bug in your markup and i'm thinking it is some weird typography and css issue, that's why I suggest you try a new technique of vertical centering, which **will work** for you.

#### online [demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2874392)

[image]

#### add to css:

```
li {
    /* … */
    position: relative;
}

li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The main trick in this demo is that in the normal flow of elements going from top to bottom, so the margin-top: auto is set to zero. However, for an absolutely positioned element acts the same distribution of free space, and similarly can be centered vertically at the specified top and bottom (does not work in `IE7`).

This trick will work with any sizes of `img`.

Comment: Thanks, it's a clean solution but it's a problem (unfortunately) if it doesn't work in IE7.